# Multiplication of Multidimensional matrices (arrays) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, multidimensional-array

First of all, I am aware that matrix and array are two different data types in NumPy. But I put both in the title to make it a general question. If you are editing this question, please feel free to remove one. Ok, here is my question,

Here is an edit to the original question. Consider a Markov Chain with a 2 dimensional state vector x_t=(y_t,z_t) where y_t and z_t are both scalars. What is the best way of representing/storing/manipulating transition matrix of this Markov Chain?

Now, what I explained is a simplified version of my problem. My Markov Chain state vector is a 5*1 vector. 
Hope this clarifies

Comment: Can you show exactly what operation you are trying to perform - of the `y_sub(i,j)=sum_over_k(x_sub(i,j,k)*y_sub(i,j,k))` kind?

Comment: @Floris: I edited my question. I hope this clarifies. Thanks for your comment and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you're trying to use a Markov chain to model english sentence syntax.  Your transition matrix will give you the probability of going from one part of speech to another part of speech.  Now let's suppose that we're using a 3<sup>rd</sup>-order Markov model.  This would give use the probability of going from state `123` to `23X`, where X is a valid state.

The Markov transition matrix would be N<sup>3</sup> x N, which is still a 2-dimensional matrix regardless of the dimensionality of the states, themselves.  If you're generating the probability distributions based on empirical evidence, then, in this case, there's going to be states with probability 0.

If you're worried about sparsity, perhaps arrays are not the best choice.  Instead of using an array of arrays, perhaps you should use a dictionary of dictionaries.  Or if you have many transition matrices, an array of dictionaries of dictionaries.

EDIT (based off comment):
You're right, that is more complicated.  Nonetheless, for any state, `(i,j)`, there exists a probability distribution for going to the next state, `(m,n)`.  Hence, we have our "outer" dictionary, whose keys are all the possible states.  Each key (state) points to a value that is a dictionary, which holds the probability distribution for that state.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope this clarifies. Thanks for your answer and help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess my problem is a little bit different because, my transitions are a bit more complicated than what you explained. My transitions are from let's say (1,3) to (2,5) or generally speaking from (i,j) to (m,n) where 0<=i,m<= P and 0<=j,n<=Q. Do you think still I can use your approach? Thanks

Comment: @NNSr, You could-- it's still a good solution.  I made another edit.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I will try it. Do you mind if I reiterate your idea so that you confirm if I got it right? You are saying I shuld have a dictionary, lets call it Dict_1. Dict_1 has keys that are all possible states. Each key refers to another dictionary, lets say Dict_1(i,j) and that dictionary has probability distribution of going from (i,j) to all other possible states. Correct? Is it painful to use NumPy functions such as matrix multiplications with this structure?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm suggesting.  When I first did something like this, I thought it was going to be ugly, but it's not bad at all, actually.  Well, I guess it depends on what you're trying to do.  If all you need to do is generate the matrices and use them to actually create some sort of chain, then it's easy.  You don't even need to use any auxiliary functions.  All you have to do is iterate through a dictionary of dictionaries.  If you're going to actually have to do matrix multiplication or other actual matrix manipulation values, then this won't work, since dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Additionally, this wouldn't work because you're not actually holding all of the possible states in the probability distribution for each state (the point of using the hash is to decrease sparsity).  If you needed it to be ordered, you could use an [ordered dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).  If you're doing anything like taking the inverse of the matrix or what have you, (A) you're going to have to have a bunch of 0's and (B), you're probably going to have to use a 2-dimensional array or a `matrix`, or write your own methods.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I really appreciate it. All I need to do is to create bunch of transition probability matrices and then multiply them together... Can I still use this method? Maybe by basic definition of matrix multiplication i.e. y_sub(i,j)=sum_over_k(x_sub(i,j,k)*y_sub(i,j,k))? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you have to multiply the transition matrices together, then so long as you can guarantee that their dimensions are appropriate, then yes, you could do this, so long as the keys for each matrix are the same.  If they're not, then you can either have an additional dictionary of key mapping between the matrices or just use an array or matrix instead of the dictionary approach.